# Julia: Why does specifying the types of arguments in functions lead to (seemingly) inconsistent behaviour?

Tags: julia, default-value, type-declaration

I have a function that takes in 7 (keyword) arguments, each with its type specified and the last one having a default value, like so:

```
function dummy(;truefalse1::S, somevar1::T, somevar2::T, somevar3::T, somevar4::T, 
                     scalarvar::Int64, truefalse2::D = falses(3, 3)) where {
    T <: Union{Array{Float64,2}, SubArray{Float64, 2}},
    S <: AbstractArray{Bool}, D <: AbstractArray{Bool}}

    ### 

end
```

The `truefalse*` arguments can either be 2-dimensional boolean arrays (BitArray{2}) or a view of it (e.g. `view(somearray, 2:4, 3:5)`). The `somevar*` arguments can either be 2-dimensional arrays of type Float64 or the "`view`" of such an array.

The above works, but this seemingly equivalent version does not (see below for test input):

```
function dummy(;truefalse1::S, somevar1::T, somevar2::T, somevar3::T, somevar4::T, 
                     scalarvar::Int64, truefalse2::S = falses(3, 3)) where {
    T <: Union{Array{Float64,2}, SubArray{Float64, 2}},
    S <: AbstractArray{Bool}}

    ### 

end
```

(In other words, the `D` type has been removed, using the `S` type for both occurrences.)

The error message is as follows:

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching #dummy#823(::SubArray{Bool,2,BitArray{2},Tuple{UnitRange{Int64},UnitRange{Int64}},false}, ::SubArray{Float64,2,Array{Float64,2},Tuple{UnitRange{Int64},UnitRange{Int64}},false}, ::SubArray{Float64,2,Array{Float64,2},Tuple{UnitRange{Int64},UnitRange{Int64}},false}, ::SubArray{Float64,2,Array{Float64,2},Tuple{UnitRange{Int64},UnitRange{Int64}},false}, ::SubArray{Float64,2,Array{Float64,2},Tuple{UnitRange{Int64},UnitRange{Int64}},false}, ::Int64, ::BitArray{2}, ::typeof(wheretonext))
Closest candidates are:
  #dummy#823(::S, ::T, ::T, ::T, ::T, ::Int64, ::S, ::typeof(dummy)) where {T<:Union{Array{Float64,2}, SubArray{Float64,2,P,I,L} where L where I where P}, S<:(AbstractArray{Bool,N} where N)} at /SomePath/someDummyCode.jl:238
Stacktrace:
 [1] (::var"#kw##dummy")(::NamedTuple{(:truefalse1, :somevar1, :somevar2, :somevar3, :somevar4, :scalarvar),Tuple{SubArray{Bool,2,BitArray{2},Tuple{UnitRange{Int64},UnitRange{Int64}},false},SubArray{Float64,2,Array{Float64,2},Tuple{UnitRange{Int64},UnitRange{Int64}},false},SubArray{Float64,2,Array{Float64,2},Tuple{UnitRange{Int64},UnitRange{Int64}},false},SubArray{Float64,2,Array{Float64,2},Tuple{UnitRange{Int64},UnitRange{Int64}},false},SubArray{Float64,2,Array{Float64,2},Tuple{UnitRange{Int64},UnitRange{Int64}},false},Int64}}, ::typeof(dummy)) at ./none:0
 [2] top-level scope at none:0
```

Here is a sample set of test input:

```
julia> using Random; Random.seed!(1234); 

julia> trf1 = rand(5, 10) .> rand(5, 10); trf2 = rand(5, 10) .> rand(5, 10);

julia> smv1 = rand(5, 10); smv2 = rand(5, 10); smv3 = rand(5, 10); smv4 = rand(5, 10);
```

These cases produce the aforementioned error using the second function declaration:

```
julia> dummy(truefalse1 = view(trf1, 2:4, 3:5), somevar1 = view(smv1, 2:4, 3:5),
              somevar2 = view(smv2, 2:4, 3:5), somevar3 = view(smv3, 2:4, 3:5),
              somevar4 = view(smv4, 2:4, 3:5), scalarvar = 1)
```

```
julia> dummy(truefalse1 = view(trf1, 2:4, 3:5), somevar1 = view(smv1, 2:4, 3:5),
              somevar2 = view(smv2, 2:4, 3:5), somevar3 = view(smv3, 2:4, 3:5),
              somevar4 = view(smv4, 2:4, 3:5), scalarvar = 1, truefalse2 = falses(3, 3))
```

However, still using the second function declaration, this case works fine:

```
julia> dummy(truefalse1 = view(trf1, 2:4, 3:5), somevar1 = view(smv1, 2:4, 3:5),
              somevar2 = view(smv2, 2:4, 3:5), somevar3 = view(smv3, 2:4, 3:5),
              somevar4 = view(smv4, 2:4, 3:5), scalarvar = 1, truefalse2 = view(trf2, 2:4, 3:5))
```

(Recall: All the above test cases work fine with the first function declaration.)

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions on what might I have done wrong or what might be the relevant subtleties in the Julia language. This is my second week coding in Julia, so I also welcome any other tips. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because in the first definition, you let `truefalse1` and `truefalse2` have different types `S` and `D`, both types being subtypes of `AbstractArray{Bool}`. Whereas in the second definition, `truefalse1` and `truefalse2` must have the same type `S` (with the constraint that `S` be a subtype of `AbstractArray{Bool}`).

The documentation for [Parametric Methods](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/methods/#Parametric-Methods-1) should explain this in more details, but maybe the the following, more minimal example can help get you a grasp of how things work:

```
# a and b can be of different types
function foo(a::S, b::T) where {
    S<:AbstractArray{Bool},
    T<:AbstractArray{Bool}}
end

# a and b must have the same type
function bar(a::S, b::S) where {
    S<:AbstractArray{Bool}}
end

# test data
a = rand(Bool, 10); # Array
b = rand(Bool, 10); # Array
c = view(b, 1:5);   # SubArray
```

The following calls all work:

```
# OK because:
# - typeof(a) == Array{Bool,1} <: AbstractArray{Bool}
# - typeof(b) == Array{Bool,1} <: AbstractArray{Bool}
# => substitute S for Array{Bool,1} and T for Array{Bool,1}
julia> foo(a, b)

# OK because:
#   typeof(a) == typeof(b) == Array{Bool,1} <: AbstractArray{Bool}
# => substitute S for Array{Bool,1}
julia> bar(a, b)

# OK because:
# - a isa Array{Bool,1} <: AbstractArray
# - c isa SubArray{Bool,...} <: AbstractArray{Bool}
# => substitute S for Array{Bool,1} and T for SubArray{Bool,...}
julia> foo(a, c)

# Not OK because typeof(a) != typeof(b)
# there is no concrete type S such that
# - a isa S
# - b isa S
# - S <: AbstractArray
# => Method does not match
julia> bar(a, c)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching bar(::Array{Bool,1}, ::SubArray{Bool,1,Array
{Bool,1},Tuple{UnitRange{Int64}},true})                                           
Closest candidates are:
  bar(::S, ::S) where S<:(AbstractArray{Bool,N} where N) at REPL[2]:3
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at REPL[9]:1
```